# Как вывести элементы по кол-ву массива?

Tags: java, массивы

Переменная задается через командную строку и по ее размеру строится массив, после чего числа в нем проверяются и консоль выдает результат. Вопрос в том, почему, к примеру, задав в консоли 10, я получаю на выходе 2,3,5,7, а не 2,3,5,7,11,13,17 и так до 10 элементов? Точнее даже не почему, я понимаю, что массив строится с 1 до 10, поэтому среди них и выводит эти 4 числа, а как заставить код вывести именно 10 элементов?
Код:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberForArray = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] array = new int[numberForArray];
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= array.length; j++) {
            if (i != j && i % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            if (2 <= i & i < array.length) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
        }
        isPrime = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: зачем вам тут вообще массив, если кроме его длины вы его никак не используете?

Comment: вы выводите на консоль переменную i, а какие значения она у вас принимает? Вот вы ожидаете увидеть число 17, а переменная i вообще такое значение может принять у вас в коде? Я так не думаю.

Comment: @tym32167 то есть мне нужно объявить переменную и указать ей определенные границы? Или же нужно задать еще переменные для пересчета параметров массива?

Comment: вам нужен цикл, где вы не просто считаете от 1 до 10, а где вы считаете количество найденных простых чисел.